# Show that $f(z)\not=0, \forall z\in \mathbb C$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose , an entire function maps the **real line** onto the circle $C=\{z:|z|=R\}, R>0$. Show that $f(z)\not=0, \forall z\in \mathbb C$.

I thought through contradictory way but I could not think further.

Any hint. ?? Please help..

> I don't know why the users attempt to close this question. Sometimes , it is not clear that how the question start or proceed to solve.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I'll think about it.

Comment: Actually didn't downvote you, but I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $f(z)\bar f (\bar z) = R^2$ on $\mathbb R .$

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking $R=1.$ I edited it.

Comment: Really, I've tried to help. I don't appreciate "so what ?" as a comment.

Comment: If $f$ is entire, then $\bar f (\bar z)$ is entire.

Comment: Does $\overline f(z)$ mean $\overline{f(z)}$?

Comment: You have the product of two entire functions, which is entire, equal to a nonzero constant on $\mathbb R.$

Comment: The hint is good if OP knows some basic properties of analytical functions (e.g. non-constant [analytical functions only have isolated zeros](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Zeroes_of_Analytic_Function_are_Isolated)) otherwise it's hard to use it. Maybe mentioning a property like this, which is possible without giving the answer away, might be useful.

Comment: Suppose you have an entire function that equals $4$ on the real axis. What must be true of this function?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 look up the identity theorem.

Comment: @@ Cameron Williams) I really can't understand how Identity theorem helps ..It states that :**If zeros of an analytic function in a connected domain has a limit point then it is identically zero**.

Comment: So if an entire function $f=4$ on the real axis, look at $f-4$.

Comment: Then $f\equiv 4$ on $\mathbb C$...and so $f\not=0$ on $\mathbb C$..Is it ??